# FullCalendar fetch events foreach resource

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

The system I currently have setup stores events and resources on the backend, with an association between them. But, the only way to get events from the API is by resource. So I can't just get all events on this date, I need to specify what resource I want to get the events from.

In fullcalendar, I'm using resources and events as functions to make ajax calls to get the data. That's fine for the resources, I can just get them. But when I need to get the events, I need to make multiple ajax calls, one for each resource. Here's some psudocode

```
var timeline = new Calendar(timelineEl,{
        initialView: 'resourceTimeline',
        resources: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback){
                ...
                //ajax call to get resources
                ...
        },
        events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback){
                /* pseudo code
                list allEvents
                foreach resource (gotten above)
                        ajax get events for that resource
                        establish association between events and that resource for FC backend
                        add events to allEvents list
                save all events
                */
        }
};
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't a simple way to get get all the resources in the event fetching method to do it this way.

What is the best way to do this then?

EDIT:

Thank you ADyson for letting me know what I was asking for wasn't clear. I'll try to better explain.

I need to make multiple ajax calls to get all of the events. I will need to get all of the events by resource, because that's how the backend is set up. The issue is that in the getEvents function that makes all those ajax calls, I need a way to check all the resources that are already in the calendar, so I can make all the calls. But I haven't been able to find a way to do that cleanly. I have managed to get something working, which I will put here when it's finished. But I don't love how I've done it so I still wanted to ask if anyone else had a better way.

Comment: If you can't change the API, then there's nothing you can do. Fullcalendar can only fetch data from the sources available. If that requires multiple AJAX calls, then that's what you have to do. Either change the API or live with it. Is this causing you a specific problem other than the slight inconvenience of having to write a bit of extra code? Is there a performance issue, perhaps? Or you don't know which resources to fetch events for until you've first fetched the resource list, perhaps? It's a bit unclear what the issue is that you want us to help with.

Comment: I think its that last one. Multiple ajax calls is fine. The issue is that I need to check all the resources and make ajax calls for each one, and that check/get is what I can't figure out. There isn't a way to call `thisCalendar.getResources()` from within the events function.

Comment: `There isn't a way to call thisCalendar.getResources() from within the events function.`...well, there is - you just call it. But yes it would be likely to return nothing because the async request to fetch those resources probably hasn't completed at the time the events function is called. It would be a tiny bit inefficient perhaps, but could you make a separate AJAX call to fetch the resources before you render the calendar, and make sure the calendar isn't rendered until that call completes. That way you'd have a list of resources ready for when you first need to fetch events.

Comment: How do you just call it? When initializing the calendar and setting the `events` option to be a function, I couldn't find a way to check the calendar that the events are for. `this` returns the window and the calendar variable isn't in scope.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, you can definitely reference it from some other other callbacks, but evidently not from the events function. Apologies.